# My figma web page design does not fit to the real page, it goes infinity to the right

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, figma

[this is the real web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeVVV.png)

[this is the Figma design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGwUE.png)

I designed a web page navigation menu in Figma, but when I opened this in the real browser it goes to infinity. How can I fix this? It must be fit to the browser.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take display size on the desktop? The pixel must be on the desktop size.